# What options can improve OCR using Google CLoud Vision?

Tags: javascript, azure, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm testing the OCR with Google cloud vision and I find the results are particularly bad. 
My documents are in french but it misses many apostrophes and commas.
For example as input [image]

With the code

```
Request
        .post(`https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=AIzaSyAtArxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxpGrKrydU4`)
        .send({
          requests: [{
            image: { content: base64.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '') },
            features: [{ type: 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION' }],
            "imageContext": { "languageHints": [ "fr" ] }
          }]
        })
```

I get the result (with errors highlighted in yellow)
[image]

When I test the same image with [Microsoft Azure OCR](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/), the result is absolutely perfect, without having to indicate the language.

Has anyone come across a similar level of inaccuracy in Google Cloud Vision ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it using `"languageHints": ["fr"]`

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "imageContext": {
        "languageHints": ["fr"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```